# CSS Buttons rounded on one side

Tags: css

I have to create a button like that :

[image]

I thought it would be easy to do that, but I have some trouble to do the rounded side (left, right), and I guess I will have problem to add the little extra color too.

I have made something like that for now (I feel like colors are not the same)

```css
.home_header_buttons {
  display: flex;
}

.home_header_buttons .btn_home {
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 2.4px;
  margin-right: -2.4px;
  line-height: 13px;
  background-color: rgba(8, 17, 23, .5);
  border: 1px solid #173c3d;
  padding: 30px 60px;
}

.home_header_buttons .btn_home:first-child {
  color: #16dcf3;
  border-right: none;
}
.home_header_buttons .btn_home:first-child::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at center, #007278 20%, #0b111a 100%);
  width: 1px;
  height: 90%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.home_header_buttons .btn_home:last-child {
  color: #64ffb1;
  border-left: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="home_header_buttons">
    <a href="#" class="btn_home">Coaching</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn_home">Order now</a>
</div>
```

I tried to do something with border-top-lef-radius and border-bottom-left-radius, but it's really ugly.

Here is how it looks in my dev side :

[image]

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 12):

You're looking for the various **[`border-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius)** properties, which can actually be specified individually.

Specifically, you're looking for **[`border-top-left-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-top-left-radius)** and **[`border-bottom-left-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-bottom-left-radius)** on `.home_header_buttons .btn_home:first-child`, and **[`border-top-right-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-top-right-radius)** and **[`border-bottom-right-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-bottom-right-radius)** on `.home_header_buttons .btn_home:last-child`.

I've gone with a value of `50px` for each in my example, and this can be seen in the following:

```css
.home_header_buttons {
  display: flex;
}

.home_header_buttons .btn_home {
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 2.4px;
  margin-right: -2.4px;
  line-height: 13px;
  background-color: rgba(8, 17, 23, .5);
  border: 1px solid #173c3d;
  padding: 30px 60px;
}

.home_header_buttons .btn_home:first-child {
  color: #16dcf3;
  border-right: none;
  border-top-left-radius: 50px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
}

.home_header_buttons .btn_home:first-child::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at center, #007278 20%, #0b111a 100%);
  width: 1px;
  height: 90%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.home_header_buttons .btn_home:last-child {
  color: #64ffb1;
  border-left: none;
  border-top-right-radius: 50px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="home_header_buttons">
  <a href="#" class="btn_home">Coaching</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn_home">Order now</a>
</div>
```

---

To add colour, unfortunately you can't colour the individual corners themselves (as this would make no sense). You need to make use of `border-left-color` and `border-right-color`. This will colour the very edges of the borders:

```css
.home_header_buttons {
  display: flex;
}

.home_header_buttons .btn_home {
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 2.4px;
  margin-right: -2.4px;
  line-height: 13px;
  background-color: rgba(8, 17, 23, .5);
  border: 1px solid #173c3d;
  padding: 30px 60px;
}

.home_header_buttons .btn_home:first-child {
  color: #16dcf3;
  border-right: none;
  border-top-left-radius: 50px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
  border-left-color: blue;
}

.home_header_buttons .btn_home:first-child::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at center, #007278 20%, #0b111a 100%);
  width: 1px;
  height: 90%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.home_header_buttons .btn_home:last-child {
  color: #64ffb1;
  border-left: none;
  border-top-right-radius: 50px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
  border-right-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="home_header_buttons">
  <a href="#" class="btn_home">Coaching</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn_home">Order now</a>
</div>
```

If you want to extend these colours, you'll need to make use of `border-top-color` and `border-bottom-color`, though keep in mind that this will colour the entire edge:

```css
.home_header_buttons {
  display: flex;
}

.home_header_buttons .btn_home {
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 2.4px;
  margin-right: -2.4px;
  line-height: 13px;
  background-color: rgba(8, 17, 23, .5);
  border: 1px solid #173c3d;
  padding: 30px 60px;
}

.home_header_buttons .btn_home:first-child {
  color: #16dcf3;
  border-right: none;
  border-top-left-radius: 50px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
  border-left-color: blue;
  border-top-color: blue;
  border-bottom-color: blue;
}

.home_header_buttons .btn_home:first-child::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at center, #007278 20%, #0b111a 100%);
  width: 1px;
  height: 90%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.home_header_buttons .btn_home:last-child {
  color: #64ffb1;
  border-left: none;
  border-top-right-radius: 50px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
  border-right-color: green;
  border-top-color: green;
  border-bottom-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="home_header_buttons">
  <a href="#" class="btn_home">Coaching</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn_home">Order now</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks you, it works great (already tried, but in percentage so it didn't worked out :() Do you've any idea how to add the litlte colors on the border ? I've tried border-left-color so, but it don't take the rounded border. Is there anyway to increase the border color area or something like that ?

Comment: Percentage values will work... though they'll look a little weird; you'll want to make use of fixed units for `border-radius`. As for colors, standard `border-left: blue` / `border-left: green` will work. Unfortunately if you want to extend the border's colour past the **very** edge of the circle, you'll need to make use of `border-top` / `border-bottom`, which will colour that whole side.

Comment: Yeah I understood, thanks you a lot, I feel really bad asking simple questions as that, but anyway, need to learn more and more ;)

Answer (score 5):

In addition to border-radius you can consider pseudo element to create the coloration

```css
.home_header_buttons {
  display: flex;
}

.home_header_buttons .btn_home {
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 2.4px;
  margin-right: -2.4px;
  line-height: 13px;
  background-color: rgba(8, 17, 23, .5);
  border: 2px solid #173c3d;
  padding: 30px 60px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.home_header_buttons .btn_home:first-child {
  color: #16dcf3;
  border-right: none;
  border-radius:50px 0 0 50px;
}
.home_header_buttons .btn_home:first-child::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:-2px;
  bottom:-2px;
  left:-2px;
  width:70px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  border-radius:inherit;
  border-right:none;
}
.home_header_buttons .btn_home:first-child::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at center, #007278 20%, #0b111a 100%);
  width: 1px;
  height: 90%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.home_header_buttons .btn_home:last-child {
  color: #64ffb1;
  border-left: none;  
  border-radius:0 50px 50px 0;
}
.home_header_buttons .btn_home:last-child::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:-2px;
  bottom:-2px;
  right:-2px;
  width:70px;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  border-radius:inherit;
  border-left:none;
}
body {
 background:pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="home_header_buttons">
    <a href="#" class="btn_home">Coaching</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn_home">Order now</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, thanks you. Damn, You all resolved my problem in few minutes, when I'm on it since like 20 minutes, thanks you all

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure how to add the color on the outside, but border-radius will allow you to round the left and right.  The easiest way would be to round the radius of the container:

```
your-container {
  border-radius: 500px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 500px;
}
```