# css input border radius on all corners causes a strange shadow

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a 'rounded' like input boxes and while rounding the corner in CSS it created this strange shadow, and I can't seem to figure out what is causing it

```css
.form-wrapper {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 2em 0px;


}
    .password-input input{
        border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    }
    input {
        width:400px;
        padding: 3em;
    }
    input::placeholder {
        color: gray;
    }
    .email-input input{
        border-top-left-radius: 10px;
        border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="input-field email-input">
    <input id="email" type="text" class="validate" placeholder="Enter Your Email Adress"/>
  </div>
  <div class="input-field password-input">
    <input id="password" type="text" class="validate" placeholder="Enter Your Password"/>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm not sure on this 'strange shadow' you are talking about. All that is changing is that the lines are becoming thicker, which is the expected behaviour...

Comment: Those thicker lines are what I'm referring too. I figured that the border width (default) 1px would stay the same all around. Just as the bottom left stayed corner stayed normal.

Comment: They're coming from the `border-radius: 10px`. Unfortunately, there's no 'corner' `border-radius` property; `bottom-left` will be applied to both the `bottom` and `left` **edges** in their entirety. If you want to avoid this and rather colour the very edges, you might be able to make use of `border-color`, as is illustrated in [**this example**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52194379/2341603).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not **strange behaviour its intended**. The `input` elements are taking the default style for border.

You need to override the default border style of `input` tag. Use `border: 1px solid silver;` to override default border style for input.

```css
.form-wrapper {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 2em 0px;
}
.password-input input{
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
input {
    width:400px;
    padding: 3em;
    border: 1px solid silver;  /* <-- Override default border */
}
input::placeholder {
    color: gray;
}
.email-input input{
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="input-field email-input">
    <input id="email" type="text" class="validate" placeholder="Enter Your Email Adress"/>
  </div>
  <div class="input-field password-input">
    <input id="password" type="text" class="validate" placeholder="Enter Your Password"/>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

This strange shadow is there because you have border-radius without border. Just add border of your desired color.

```css
.form-wrapper {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 2em 0px;


}
    .password-input input{
        border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
    }
    input {
        width:400px;
        padding: 3em;
    }
    input::placeholder {
        color: gray;
    }
    .email-input input{
        border-top-left-radius: 10px;
        border-top-right-radius: 10px;
 border: 1px solid #999;
border-bottom: 0;
    }
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="input-field email-input">
    <input id="email" type="text" class="validate" placeholder="Enter Your Email Adress"/>
  </div>
  <div class="input-field password-input">
    <input id="password" type="text" class="validate" placeholder="Enter Your Password"/>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Write a css **border** property in HTML5 input tag !

```css
.form-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 2em 0px;
}

.password-input input {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

input {
  width: 400px;
  padding: 3em;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

input::placeholder {
  color: gray;
}

.email-input input {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="input-field email-input">
    <input id="email" type="text" class="validate" placeholder="Enter Your Email Adress" />
  </div>
  <div class="input-field password-input">
    <input id="password" type="text" class="validate" placeholder="Enter Your Password" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

By default there is no border on the input, so you can either add `border:1px solid color` otherwise it will show nothing

```css
.form-wrapper {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 2em 0px;


}
    .password-input input{
        border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    }
    input {
        width:400px;
        padding: 3em;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
    input::placeholder {
        color: gray;
    }
    .email-input input{
        border-top-left-radius: 10px;
        border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="input-field email-input">
    <input id="email" type="text" class="validate" placeholder="Enter Your Email Adress"/>
  </div>
  <div class="input-field password-input">
    <input id="password" type="text" class="validate" placeholder="Enter Your Password"/>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution from another question on stack found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19049674/border-radius-issue-with-input-type-text)

adding `border:none` and the styling after solve it, which is still strange to me.

```
  border: none; /* <-- This thing here */
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simplify things?

```
        <html>
    <head>
    <style> 
.form-wrapper {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 2em 0px;
}

.field{
display:block;
width:400px;
border:1px solid green;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
     border-top-left-radius: 10px;
        border-top-right-radius: 10px;   
        }

#input1 {
width:100%;
border:0px; border-top:0px solid red;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px; 
}

#input2 {
width:100%;
border:0px; border-top:1px solid red;        
border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;}


input {
min-height:80px;
height:auto;
padding: 3em;
    }
    input::placeholder {
        color: gray;        
    }

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
<form>
  <div class="field">
    <input id="input1" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Email Adress"/> <br>
    <input id="input2" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Password"/>
  </div>
</form> 
    </body>
    </html>
```